# Display SCNText at midpoint of two nodes in ARKit

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, augmented-reality, arkit

I am placing the two nodes at two different position in the ARKit scene. After that I am drawing a line between the those two nodes. Then I am displaying distance at the second node position. But I need to display SCNText at midpoint of two nodes. Please help me to display SCNText at midpoint of two nodes.

Here I am sharing  my code: this is how I am displaying text at second node.

```
    let textGeometry = SCNText(string: String(format: "%.1f", distance), extrusionDepth: 1.0) 
    textGeometry.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 5)
    textGeometry.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.red
    let textNode = SCNNode(geometry: textGeometry)
    textNode.position = SCNVector3Make(point.x, point.y, point.z)
    textNode.scale = SCNVector3Make(0.002, 0.002, 0.002)
    let eulerAngles = self.sceneView.session.currentFrame?.camera.eulerAngles
    textNode.eulerAngles = SCNVector3((eulerAngles?.x)!, (eulerAngles?.y)!, (eulerAngles?.z)! + Float(1.57))
    sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(textNode)
```

Comment: textNode.position = SCNVector3Make((point1.x + point2.x)/2.0, (point1.y + point2.y)/2.0, (point1.z + point2.z)/2.0)

Comment: Tq E.Coms, its working now.